# Getting type Mismatch error with List of Maps

Tags: scala, json4s

I have method which should except a string and List of Map. 
I get an error on the second line as **// get error as : type mismatch; found : List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] required: List[Map[String,org.json4s.JValue]] (which expands to) List[Map[String,org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue]**:

```
val a =  List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo"))
val r = jsonFieldUpdater(json, a)
```

If I do this

```
val r = jsonFieldUpdater(json,  List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo")))
```

it works. How can I work in the first?

Comment: `val a: List[Map[String,org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] =  List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala type inference has inferred `Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "foo")` as `Map[String, Any]` as Common super type of `Int` and `String` is `Any`

Guide the Scala compiler using explicit type annotation like this

```
val a: List[Map[String,org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue] =  List(Map("inner/age" -> 35, "age" -> 27, "name" -> "foo"))
val r = jsonFieldUpdater(json, a)
```

*Note that this code will work in the proper context only because Ints and Strings are considered as `org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue` in the code*